# JSF 2.1.7/2.1.17 on Glassfish 3.1.2.2: managed beans not resolved

Tags: jsf, glassfish, managed-bean, mojarra

My JSF application works on JBoss 7.1.1.
I tried on Glassfish 3.1.2.2(newest), all managed beans are not recognized.
The same version of Mojarra 2.1.7 is used in both cases.

```
[#|2013-03-07T17:33:36.734-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /view.xhtml @13,75 listener="#{viewBean.preRenderView}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'viewBean' resolved to null
       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2486)
       at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2168)
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2116)
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:288)
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:246)
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
```

Facelet page:

```
<f:view locale="#{viewBean.locale}"> 
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{viewBean.preRenderView}" />
....
</f:view>
```

From debugging, all managed beans with @ManagedBean annotation are not built. So all managed beans are resolved to null.

```
@ManagedBean(name="viewBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean  {
....
}
```

It works on JBoss 7.

Anyone uses Grassfish 3 with Mojarra 2.1.7? I replaced the jsf impl with javax.faces.2.1.17, no luck, same error.

Thanks for any help.
Dave

Comment: There must be a problem in your web.xml configuration and/or in your Facelets page. Please add more info in order to help you.

Comment: @Dave Glassfish comes prebundled with Mojarra 2.1.6, so perhaps there is a class loading conflict between the prebundled JSF implementatation and your providing of 2.1.7?  Also check to make sure that you are loading the correct EL implementation and that your web.xml is correctly loading the 3.0 web app XSD.

Comment: I copied the javax.faces 2.1.7 to replace the 2.1.6 coming with glassfish, copied the hibernate 4.1.10 to glassfish/lib. I did not change the javax.el jar in glassfish. I just changed the web.xml xsd version 2.5 to 3.0 as you suggested, same error. It works in JBoss 7. thanks.

Comment: How is your `faces-config.xml` declared?